# How to verify method was called

Tags: ios, ocmockito

I want to test a certain method was called in response to an NSNotification being received

i've tried this:

```
_sut = mock([EAMainScreenViewController class]);
[_sut view];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:kNotificationPushReceived object:[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate userInfo:nil];
[verify(_sut) pushReceived:anything()];
```

And my _sut viewDidLoad looks like this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(pushReceived:) name:kNotificationPushReceived object:[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate];
}
```

why does my test fail expecting 1 invocation, and receiving 0 invocations ?

btw, if i debug - the debugger does stop at the method

Comment: Where do you test number of invocations?

Comment: verify(_sut) someMethod: should test that it happened at least once

Comment: Are you sure it shouldn't be `verify([_sut pushReceived:anything()]);` instead?

Comment: that version does not build

Comment: What does `-pushReceived:` actually do?

Comment: it notifies the app that a push notification has been received
I mocked the push notification and sent it as a NSNotificationCenter message, push received is supposed to intercept that message

Comment: the test is supposed to check that there was a registered listener for the notification

Comment: I'm sorry but `subject under test` must not be mocked

Comment: Can you share what happens in `pushReceived`? I assume you're showing next controller or calling some method in app delegate?

Comment: @EugenMartynov it does not matter what pushReceived does, the method is trying to test if push received was invoked, not if the logic of push received works correctly

Comment: So you're trying to test that `NotificationCenter` called your observer? So you don't trust apple engineers that they wrote framework code correctly? If so, you have to register your mocked `_sut` yourself. When you call `[_sut view]` it will not call original method (this is expected behaviour for mocks)

Comment: No - I don't trust developer not deleting this line from the class it supposed to appear in without good reason, or the developer to write the correct name of the notification or some other such

Answer (score 0):

You should re-write your test to next:

```
- (void)setUp {
    _sut = [[EAMainScreenViewController alloc] <properInit>];
}

- (void)tearDown {
    //just in case
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:_sut];
}

- (void)testThatNotificationPushReceived {
    [_sut viewDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kNotificationPushReceived object:<probably some mock> userInfo:nil];

    //test something that happens with your mock
}
```

Comment: what good does it do if i register my _sut to be the listener for the notification, when the method should test if my original view controller has registered to listen to the notification !?